# Can You Build A Chrome Extension Using Django?

Tags: django, google-chrome-extension

I am building a Chrome Extension for my team to input information that will store data as efficiently as possible. I know Chrome Extensions are built with JavaScript, but was wondering if I could use Django to build a Chrome Extension?

My plan would be to build the App using Django, and then host using AppEngine.

Thanks for the feedback! I was unable to find any Google results discussing developing Chrome Extensions using Django.

-Adam

Answer (score 8):

Like you said, the actual Chrome Extension will need to be built using JavaScript. However, you can always use anything you want as the back-end (Django, Ruby on Rails, Node.js, etc.). This would work just like a normal web app except that you replace the .html file that you send to a client's browser with the Chrome Extension. The Chrome Extension sends standard POST or XHR requests just like any web page, then Django processes the request and sends back a response which your Extension will consume in the request callback.